# How long does it take until click event is triggered?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I try to make a select box whose entries are opened after clicking into the input box. After selecting one of the items, the dropdown should be closed again.
I want to achieve the open/close part of the dropdown without the use of javascript.

The html looks like this:

```
<div id="outer">
  <input type="text" id="input">
  <div id="results">
    <div>Test 1 </div>
    <div>Test 2 </div>
    <div>Test 3 </div>
    <div>Test 4 </div>    
  </div>
</div>
<div id="label">
</div>
```

After clicking onto an item, the selected value should appear below the `#outer` div (just for demonstration purposes).
The Javascript for assigning click events to the dropdown values:

```
document.querySelectorAll("#results div").forEach(setClick);
function setClick(node) {
     node.addEventListener("click", setText.bind(null, node.innerHTML))
}
function setText(t) {
    document.getElementById("label").innerHTML = t;
}
```

Now I will show you my first draft of css code:

```
#outer {
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
}
#input {
  width: 100%;
}
#results {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    visibility: hidden;
    background-color: white;
}
#results > div:hover {
  background-color: lightblue;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#outer:focus-within #results, #results:hover {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

This works like a charm but fails in one point:
After clicking an item, the dropdown is not closed. This is because of the `#results:hover` selector which is needed to keep the dropdown open after clicking onto an item. The click takes the focus out of the input field, thus the `focus-within` selector is not applied anymore. As the focus is removed from the input before the click occurs, the dropdown is hidden when the final click arrives in the document (this is my understanding of the problem).
Thus I use the `hover` selector which forces the div to keep open as long as the mouse is above the div.

You can test this here:
https://jsfiddle.net/hcetz1og/3/

My solution for this was a transition that hides the dropdown after the focus has been taken away:

```
#outer:not(:focus-within) #results:hover {
  visibility: hidden;
  transition-property: visibility;
  /*use 10 ms and the clicked value in the drop down won't be shown */
  transition-delay: 100ms;
  transition-timing-function: step-end;
}
```

This works on my machine when I use 100ms as a delay. If I use 10ms, I have the same problem again. It seems that the click event is triggered "very" late.

Feel free to test it here: 
https://jsfiddle.net/hcetz1og/2

**Question:**
How long will it take until the click event arrives at the document? Is there a fixed time span I have to wait or can the delay depend on every machine?
If so, I am forced to not use plain CSS but must use javascript for this I think.

**Edit**:
Feel free to post an alternative solution using plain css. But please be aware that I mainly want to focus on getting an answer to this question, not alternative solutions.

Comment: i don't think it is a delay after the click but rather you need to mouse out after the click??? or so it seems for me

Comment: @PaddyHallihan Yes, I need to mouse out to force the `hover` selector to not be applied anymore. For this I introduced the second solution. By using a transition with `step-end` I am ensuring that the dropdown is "moved" away from the user's mouse position, forcing the `hover` to be disabled. But when this happens too early, the click seems not to touch the result items, otherwise the item's value should be rendered below the `outer` div. I am not sure about the exact process here. It is only a assumption by me. Maybe someone knows in depth what is happening here.

Comment: The time for a click event to trigger should be really short. It's impossible to say exactly how short because it depend on the computing power, browser and other factors. Therefore a design that depends on timings like this is bad in my opinion and should be avoided if possible. It is as asking for problems. A javascript solution based on event handlers would be much more reliable and easy to implement. Not sure if it can be accomplished with css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Mark Baijens said in the comments, using timeouts is a bad practice, so here is a pretty clean solution.
I used JavaScript to render the dropdown, not the CSS, because the CSS is where Your issue is coming from.

I don't know why would You want to set the `innerHTML`, but not some other property, like `style.visibility` for example. It just doesn't make sense to me, so with that in mind, let's get our hands on this :)

#### Working demo [>> HERE <<](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/moYzGQ).

#### Step 1 - remove the `#outer...:hover` parts of CSS

So, You are left with this:

```
#outer {
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
}
#input {
  width: 100%;
}
#results {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    visibility: hidden;
    background-color: white;
}
#results > div:hover {
  background-color: lightblue;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

#### Step 2 - add the `onfocus` event to the `input` field

Just assign a function call to the `onfocus` attribute of the input. **Everything else in the HTML stays the same.**

```
<div id="outer">
  <input type="text" id="input" onfocus="showElements()">
  <div id="results">
    <div>Test 1 </div>
    <div>Test 2 </div>
    <div>Test 3 </div>
    <div>Test 4 </div>    
  </div>
</div>
<div id="label">
</div>
```

#### Step 3 - create the `showElements` and `hideElements` function:

```
function showElements() {
  document.getElementById("results").style.visibility = 'visible';
}
function hideElements() {
  document.getElementById("results").style.visibility = 'hidden';
}
```

#### Step 4 - call the `hideElements()` when clicked outside the `input` element

There are two cases for the click outside the `input` element:

- Case 1 - we clicked on one of the `div`s inside the `#results` wrapper
- Case 2 - clicking outside the input field, but not on one of the `div`s inside the `#results` wrapper

In the **first case**, we will modify the assignment of the `onclick` handler like this:

```
document.querySelectorAll("#results div").forEach(setClick);
function setClick(node) {
  node.addEventListener("click", setTextAndHideElements.bind(null, node.innerHTML));
}
```

So, the `setText` function now becomes `setTextAndHideElements` and looks like this:

```
function setTextAndHideElements(t) {
  document.getElementById("label").innerHTML = t;
  hideElements();
}
```

For the **second case** (clicking outside the input field, but not on one of the `div`s inside the `#results` wrapper), we must watch for the click on the whole page (`document` element), and respond to the action like this:

```
document.onclick = function(e) {
  if (e.target.id !== 'input'){
    hideElements();
  }
}
```

Note: this will override any previously assigned `onclick` events assigned to the `document` element.

#### As mentioned in the beginning, working demo is [>> HERE (codepen.io) <<](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/moYzGQ).

Comment: As mentioned, this was only a minimal working example. Replace the innerHtml with anything you like more. Thanks for your investigation :-). Of course I know some kind of Javascript solutions (but I did not thought about using `onfocus` event for this. Seems reasonable to prefer this over a pure onclick based solution). The CSS solution would have been cleaner in my opinion. That was the reason for trying this. Unfortunatelly, the event order forces me to use this kind of timeout.

Comment: Using `onfocus` or `:focus-within` in CSS both deal with the `focus` of an element. The difference is in readability and quality of the solution. If You end up using my code (or most of it), please accept this answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

I tried another solution which requires no setting of additional JS events. 
See: https://jsfiddle.net/hcetz1og/4/

I gave every `result item` a tabindex of "0" to ensure, those items can be focusable.
Then i removed the `#outer:not()` part from the css and replaced the `hover` selector with this: `#results:focus-within`. Additional I called `node.blur()` on the node after clicking onto them.

Summary:
Change in HTML:

```
<div tabindex="0">Test 1 </div>
```

Change in JS:

```
function setText(t, node) {
    document.getElementById("label").innerHTML = t;
  node.blur();
}
```

Change in CSS:

```
#outer:focus-within #results, #results:focus-within {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

What do you think about this one? Should be stable I think because the focus onto the `#results` div is set before the `click` event is triggered onto the result item.
Event order should be (based on my observation):

`input focus -> input blur -> item focus -> item click`

Not sure if the step between blur and focus can lead to a visible problem. Theoretically, the results div must be hidden and shown again in a very small amount of time.
But I investigated this with chrome's performance timeline and did not recognize a new render between both events. One can see, that the result item is focused (outline is set onto it) and then it disappears as expected.

Comment: This will work, but it is far more complicated for understanding, I think. You should not write code that is hard to read and understand, that is why I think that JS solution is a better fit. CSS should handle styling of elements, but the logic of how something operates should be handled by JS. That's just my opinion.

Comment: @Casper that is a good point! I think you're right. If another developer looks into my code, it would not be clear how this is working. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: I am glad I helped :)